# set default today date and time from server in datetimepicker addon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

Need to set default date and time from server in datetime picker.I can choose a setDate but i need to set today highlighted date from server,and click now button it should shows the server date and time.please suggest some solution.

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon

```
var dt = new Date("2015 10 12,10:00:00");

$('#basic_example_1').datetimepicker();
$("#basic_example_1").datetimepicker('setDate', dt);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pw075c2L/)**

Comment: what server side code are you using

Answer (score 1):

frame your code like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var dt = new Date("<?php echo date('Y m d,H:i:s'); ?>");

$('#basic_example_1').datetimepicker();
$("#basic_example_1").datetimepicker('setDate', dt);
</script>
```